# create choices dynamically in django

Tags: python, django, model

I'm trying to populate choices in django form dynamically, the choices cames from an external API.
My model so far:

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):

choice_field = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=())

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
    api_url = 'http://api.com'
    response = requests.get(api_url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        
        data = response.json()
        options = [(option['value'], option['label']) for option in data]
       
        self._meta.get_field('choice_field').choices = options
```

however, it is not working, can someone help me?

Comment: Use a second model, populate records with the API.

Answer (score 0):

if you can use **Django 5.0**; from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.choices):

> choices can also be defined as a callable that expects no arguments
> and returns any of the formats described above. For example:
>
> ```py
> def get_currencies():
>     return {i: i for i in settings.CURRENCIES}
>
>
> class Expense(models.Model):
>     amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
>     currency = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=get_currencies)
> ```
>
> Passing a callable for `choices` can be particularly handy when, for
> example, the choices are:
>
> the result of I/O-bound operations (which could potentially be
> cached), such as querying a table in the same or an external database,
> or accessing the choices from a static file. a list that is mostly
> stable but could vary from time to time or from project to project.
> Examples in this category are using third-party apps that provide a
> well-known inventory of values, such as currencies, countries,
> languages, time zones, etc.

so you would do this basicly:

```py
def get_choices:
    api_url = 'http://api.com'
    response = requests.get(api_url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        return [(option['value'], option['label']) for option in data]
    else:
        pass #error handling here

#---------------------------------

from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
     choice_field = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=get_choices)
```

Also note this from the documentation as well:

> Note that choices can be any sequence object – not necessarily a list
> or tuple. This lets you construct choices dynamically. But if you find
> yourself hacking `choices` to be dynamic, you’re probably better off
> using a proper database table with a `ForeignKey`. `choices` is meant for
> static data that doesn’t change much, if ever.